# Dependent Drop Downs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I must be having brainfade but I can't get two dependent drop-downs to work.

In the Page load event I am setting the values in my first dropdown if this is not a postback. In the selectedindexchanged event of this drop down I am clearing a second drop-down and adding items based upon the value in the first drop-down. The items are added manually with no use of data-binding.

If I step through the code I can see that the second drop-down is cleared and items are added to it correclty. However, they don't appear in the web page - the second drop-down remains empty.

Help

### UPDATE

Thanks for all the suggestions. I found the problem. The page used an Infragistics asynch panel for ajax postbacks. This was causing the issue.

Comment: Are you adding the items manually, or are you using data binding?

Comment: Manually. ListItem li = new ListItem(), etc.

Comment: The way you describe it sounds ok. Can you show some code?
The Page_load and the DropDown1_OnSelectedIndex_Changed would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try populating the controls at Page_Init if not IsPostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simplified interpretation of what you have described.

Markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbFirst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="lbFirst_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:ListBox>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbSecond" runat="server">
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            lbFirst.Items.Add(new ListItem("Cars", "cars", true));
            lbFirst.Items.Add(new ListItem("Trucks", "trucks", true));
        }
    }

    protected void lbFirst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbSecond.Items.Clear();
        lbSecond.Items.AddRange(GetListItems(lbFirst.SelectedValue));
    }

    private ListItem[] GetListItems(string value)
    {
        var items = new List<ListItem>();

        if(value == "cars")
        {
            items.Add(new ListItem("Camry"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Civic"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Camry"));
        }

        if(value == "trucks")
        {
            items.Add(new ListItem("Tundra"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Ford F150"));
            items.Add(new ListItem("Ranger"));
        }

        return items.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This works exactly as intended to work. Does your code look like this, or am I missing something? If you could comment I would be more than happy to help further.